# Does the time reported in z3 (v4.4.0) statistics include the time required to read the SMT constraint file?

Tags: z3, smt

Or is it purely the solving time? This question is for the case when z3 is being called as an external binary. I am asking this as in some of my examples, the constraint solving time is small and I suspect will become comparable to file read time. Also, how accurate is the total-time for small values (< 1s for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the total time should include the time need to read the problem. Those numbers are 'reasonably' precise, but not totally exact. In our own performance experiments, we usually use higher precision external timers, but usually we don't need to measure the load time.

If you're getting into the region where the load time and the solving time are both very small, then it would be best to switch to the API instead of dumping .smt2 files and then calling an external binary.